# Do I have suggest.build and how often?

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I use two types of `suggesters`:

1. one that use `dictionary file`.
2. and another that use `field for suggest`.

When I use 1st `suggester`, then `query` look like

```
/solr/iLab/suggest?q=ac&suggest.dictionary=suggest_infix_user&wt=json&suggest.build=true
```

The parameter `suggest.build=true` I have to use only first time, because I have a ready dictionary.

But if I use 2nd `suggester`, do I have to use `suggest.build` parameter and how often?

Comment: I'm sorry... come again?

Comment: I tried formatting the question into something more readable, but somebody familiar with Solr would probably have a better shot at it than I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, that I found the answer. 
  Create the dictionary for use by the suggester. In typical applications, one needs to build the dictionary before using it. However, it may not always be necessary as it is possible to setup the suggester with a dictionary that already exists. So suggest.build=true is used for it. Default value is false. And build=true is used, when index changes.